# Find which dependency includes a Spring WebApplicationInitializer

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I have a project that includes various Spring dependencies.

```
    'org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.2.RELEASE',
    'org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.3.2.RELEASE',
    'org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.2.RELEASE',
    'org.springframework:spring-web:4.3.2.RELEASE'
```

...and lots of other dependencies.

When it I deploy it to Tomcat 8.5.8 I see this message...

```
1 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
```

The message matches the one in spring-framework source code at [SpringServletContainerInitializer.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/SpringServletContainerInitializer.java) From that source code and docs it seems clear that

- Tomcat will scan classpath for non-abstract construct-able classes that implement WebApplicationInitializer and that SpringServletContainerInitializer will create an instance of each class found.
- Some library or dependency may include a WebApplicationInitializer that is found and instantiated.
- Spring itself includes WebApplicationInitializers but they all appear to be Abstract.

My code does not have a WebApplicationInitializer.

**Question:** I want to find the Initializer that some library has included, to understand which library is including it.

**Approaches that come to mind are...**

1. Get Spring-Framework or Tomcat source code. Put a breakpoint in SpringServletContainerInitializer or in Tomcat's ContextConfig class and inspect what classes are found and used.
2. Hack up the project, taking away dependencies until the WebApplicationInitializer goes away. (complex)

**Isn't there a better (quicker) way, i.e. turn on some level of logging?**

I have tried some detailed logging instructions from Tomcat and Spring docs with no success.

I'm going to get the Tomcat source. Surely I will learn something.

Comment: What's so hard about the breakpoint? Seems simple and straight forward to me.

Comment: It's not hard. I am looking for a quicker way. Time spent reverse engineering spring and tomcat is time spent not building features.

Comment: Open `WebApplicationInitializer` in your IDE -> Show Hierarchy shows you the implementations.

Comment: @M.Deinum If I were searching for implementations in my code or in libraries for which I have source and can build this would be an instant answer. My code has no implementation and I don't have source & buildable projects for most external libraries. However, I found an implementation in Jersey by searching source code, and that implementation has some odd looking default assumptions about Spring.

Comment: You only need the classes to be able to build a class hierarchy not the sources.

Comment: @M.Deinum that certainly sounds true, since Tomcat scans classes for the same . information. But I have not figured out how to get the IDE to do that without building from sources. Seems like a good lead though.

Comment: Import your project, right click on the class, show hierarchy (something like that). How to do that depends on your IDE (check the documentation of your IDE).

Comment: @M.Deinum It also depends on every library I have. They have every type of project file, build tool, project structure, IDE bias. That sounds a lot like what I'm used to, except the idea of importing a project without source code. I have not seen that. Thanks.

Comment: How are you developing your software, command line with vi? Judging from the code you use Gradle both Intellij and Eclipse have support to import those projects. You are too hung up on the fact that you need sources, you don't and in most case you only have sources for classes/code you own.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173045/discussion-between-joshp-and-m-deinum).

Answer (score 0):

Two methods worked.

1. Get the source code for tomcat, spring-framework, jersey and debug the startup process in Netbeans ....finding that

   - Tomcat processed ServletContainerInitializers from Jasper, Tomcat's own Websockets service, and `SpringServletContainerInitializer`. (expected/documented)
   - Tomcat passed to SpringServletContainerInitializer a WebApplicationInitializer from Jersey called `org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.SpringWebApplicationInitializer` which assumes you have an applicationContext.xml on your classpath in my case.

This gave me the information I was looking for.

2. Based on M Deinum's comments I tried importing my project to IntelliJ and do a global search (shift-shift on Mac) for WebApplicationInitializer.

   - This works with no further preparation because IntelliJ's global search uses some combination of reflection and their Java decompiler to read library jars and find usages and then display decompiled source code for the results.
   - The warning message that pops up when you display decompiled source the first time makes it clear.

To my knowledge, Netbeans does not have this automated scan plus decompiler option for searching through dependency jars.

The quickest route to the answer, if you have IntelliJ was the global search.